# How can I identify what is the problem in this YAML file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, trino

I got this code from https://github.com/trinodb/charts/blob/main/charts/trino/templates/configmap-catalog.yaml and I am unable to fix the indent or : or , issue in this. How can I identify what the problem is?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "trino.catalog" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "trino.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "trino.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
    role: catalogs
data:
  tpch.properties: |
    connector.name=tpch
    tpch.splits-per-node=4
  tpcds.properties: |
    connector.name=tpcds
    tpcds.splits-per-node=4
{{- range $catalogName, $catalogProperties := .Values.additionalCatalogs }}
  {{ $catalogName }}.properties: |
    {{- $catalogProperties | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details?, like error message..

Comment: Are you using this as-is? Because it's a template YAML file, where all the `{{ something }}` needs to be replaced by their actual values/strings. Maybe it's raising syntax issues after substituting values for all the `{{ ... }}`.

Comment: Adding to what @GinoMempin said: that file is part of a [helm](https://helm.sh/) template. You're not meant to apply it directly; you're meant to install the associated package using `helm install`. The `helm` command will take care of filling in the template with the necessary values.

Comment: Hello Guys, Yes you are right .. i have created a new yaml file below and applied it using helm upgrade that solved my problem.                                                
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap

additionalCatalogs:
  pinot: |-
     connector.name=pinot
     pinot.controller-urls=xxx.xxx..xxx.xx:9000

Comment: This is not a valid YAML file, it is a template that can create a valid YAML file depenending on the template substituion.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use the template file from within the Helm chart as your values definition. Instead create a separate minimal file.

I suggest you have a look at the [new Trino Helm chart user documentation](https://trino.io/docs/current/installation/kubernetes.html) for first steps.